# Agregar caracteres a una columna de un dataframe en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Trataré de ser lo más específico para poder pedir ayuda.

Tengo un dataframe obtenido de datos de texto, el cual contiene aproximadamente unas 40,000 filas y 8 columnas que son:

> `[1] "IDUSUARIO"           "NROSOLICITUD"        "MODIFICACIONRED"     "FECHASOLICITUD"      "FECHAPAGO"
>
>   [6] "FECHACONEXION"       "NROOPERACIONCREDITO" "INCUMPJUSTIFICADO"`

Las columnas `FECHASOLICITUD`, `FECHAPAGO`, y `FECHACONEXION` son de tipo char.

Puestos en contexto, lo que deseo realizar es la resta aritmética de los días entre la fecha de conexión y la fecha de solicitud, así como la fecha de conexión y de pago.

El problema que encuentro es que el formato establecido de fechas debiera ser `"dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"` y existen algunas que tienen formato `"dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm"` así como otras con formato `"d/mm/aaaa hh:mm"`, entonces, al momento de utilizar la librería `lubridate` formatea las fechas corriendose de tal manera que me las cambia al año 2020, colocando la hora como año, segundos como mes, en fin un problema total.

Tengo entendido de la versatilidad de R por lo tanto estoy tratando de utilizar la librería `stringr` para contabilizar los caracteres de fechas, que serían 19 caracteres (`dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss`). De esta manera tratar de modificar los datos que posean formato `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm` agregándoles al final de su cadena `":00"` 
agregando segundos para que no existan problemas de formato al utilizar la librería `lubridate` y agregar un `"0"` al inicio de las fechas que tienen formato `d/mm/aaaa hh:mm` para las fechas de 1-9.

Esa es la forma que se me ocurre a mi, pero si alguno de ustedes tiene una forma mucho más fácil o una manera más para poder ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estas usando `lubridate` puedes aprovechar la función [`parse_date_time()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/parse_date_time) y 
especificar los múltiples formatos posibles. En tu ejemplo pareciera que hay 3, algo así, sería lo que podrías hacer:

```
library(lubridate)

fecha <- c('20/05/2019 21:01:13',
           '20/05/2019 21:01',
           '5/05/2019 21:01')


parse_date_time(fecha, c("d/m/y H:M:S", "d/m/y H:M", "d/m/y H:M"))

[1] "2019-05-20 21:01:13 UTC" "2019-05-20 21:01:00 UTC"
[3] "2019-05-05 21:01:00 UTC"
```